# Turning a (dual boot) Ubuntu 9 into a virtual machine

Tags: backup, virtualbox, vmware, ubuntu-9.10

I have a dual boot box (Ubuntu 9 and Vista) and I'm about to upgrade Vista to Win 7. Being Ubuntu my main development environment, I'd like to use it as it is from the new environment via VirtualBox or VMWare. I know tools like clonezilla that backup entire drives; in my case, the linux partitions are distributed between several disks which in turn contain both linux and windows data. My intention is to use some backup tool (like Clonezilla if it fits) that allows me to ONLY backup the linux partitions distributed in several disks.

Any hints ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the free [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/).

Also I made some experiences with Acronis True Image, it worked well for me.